# Post multiple check box with same name

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with multiple checkbox with same name in Bootstrap when I POST form Without any selection of checkbox then also it will send `0` as value

**My actual Code**

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="vollyball">Volly Ball</label>
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="football">FootBall</label>
    <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="cricket">Cricket</label>
</div>
```

**Generated Code**

```
<div class="controls">
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="vollyball">Volly Ball
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="CheckBoxInterest_" name="interest[]">
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
     <input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="football">FootBall
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="CheckBoxInterest_" name="interest[]">
    </label>
    <label class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="interest[]" value="cricket">Cricket
    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="CheckBoxInterest_" name="interest[]">
   </label>
</div>
```

1. When I do not select any check box then also post all checkbox with value 0.
2. When I Post selected check box then also post all checkbox with `0` value and `selected` checkbox.

**Question**

How can I post only selected checkbox value and omit `0` when I post form?

Comment: what do you mean by Generated Code

Comment: Browser will generated code mentioned there and my actual code

Comment: you cannot have same name `interest[]` for checkbox and hidden element

Comment: strange, i am using chrome and i do not see this generated code in source and your Actual code seems to work just fine

Comment: I am using `BootStrap` admin panel and `cakephp` framework.

Comment: are you posting via ajax?

Comment: No Direct post through Form POST